# Do classes containing a method that return a disposable object need to implement IDisposable?

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I know that as a rule, we should implement `IDisposable` on types that contain instances of disposable objects (fields or properties). Now, does that also apply to classes containing methods that return a disposable object?

**Real life example:**

```
class MyClass
{
    public Image GetImage()
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream))
        {
            return new Bitmap(img);
        }
    }
}
```

If the answer is no, then what's the difference between the previous code and the following?

**Read-only property instead of a method:**

```
class MyClass
{
    public Image Image
    {
        get
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream))
            {
                return new Bitmap(img);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since you are using a `using` statement you _already_ are disposing the resource.  Your `GetImage()` method is fine as is.  Your `MyClass` has nothing at the class level that needs to be disposed

Comment: @maccettura Note that I'm returning a `new Bitmap`.

Comment: I think the confusing part is "fields or properties". "Properties" here means props that assign the value to a backing field (or even auto-props). It's about if your class stores the value or not. A getter returning a newly created instance is just the same as a method. No need to implement `IDisposable` here. What would you want to dispose anyway if you didn't store the instance?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I understand.  But your method returns the new Bitmap and then immediately disposes the resources it used to get that Bitmap

Comment: @maccettura but the new bitmap is still a *new* disposable object.

Comment: Once you return the new bitmap it ceases to be your responsibility, its up to the caller to dispose of it.

Comment: @RenéVogt So, a read-only property doesn't store the instance, and therefore no resources need to be disposed. Did I understand you correctly?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed the object you are returning may implement `IDisposable` but thats not a problem for `MyClass` , thats up to whatever calls that method to dispose.  Besides, what would you dispose of?  Once that Bitmap is returned its gone, what on earth would you do in your `Dispose()` method?

Comment: Okay, I get it now, the *backing field* is the key here. That's what I was missing. Thank you all :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed I dont think you got it yet, I don't understand what you mean by "the backing field is the key".  The thing you need to understand is your method _and_ the property both **return** something that is `IDisposable`, the class itself has no unmanaged resources so there is nothing to `Dispose()` in the class.

Comment: @maccettura yes, I totally understand that now. Compare my property with another one that has a setter, it makes a big difference, right? That's what I was confused about. It makes sense now that having a backing field makes the class need to implement IDisposable. That's what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now, does that also apply to classes containing methods that return a disposable object?

No, the class is not responsible for whatever it returns to the caller. The caller has to properly dispose the obtained resource.

That said, your second example is basically the same as the first. The property does not have a backing field so the class is not storing a reference to the returned value. In fact, the compiler will end up creating a method called `get_Image()` that will be the same as the first example.

Comment: Yes, it makes sense now that the *backing field* is the key. Thanks for clearing the confusion that I had :)

Answer (score 3):

Your class doesn't retain the unmanaged object for itself. It returns the unmanaged object to the caller. The caller is responsible for the unmanaged object.

Your property likewise doesn't retain the unmanaged object for the instance of your class. A property implementation that *would* require your class to implement `IDisposable` would look like this:

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public Image Image { get; }

    public MyClass(byte[] byteArray)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream))
        {
            Image = new Bitmap(img);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose() { ... }
    public virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) { ... }
}
```

Comment: So, setting the read-only property from the constructor makes a difference. That's also a good point.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed It does because that's no longer the same, it's an auto-implemented read-only property in this example (where the compiler would generate a `_image` field for you)

Comment: @Ahmed Abdelhameed: You could say that, although auto properties are just properties where you don't have to write the backing fields yourself. Mainly, your original implementation doesn't assign or *store* state anywhere.

Comment: Yep, it does make a perfect sense now. Thank you both, I upvoted both your answers.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer would be no, you don't need to implement `IDisposable`.

Since you are returning an object to which you have no reference in your class, this is no more your classes responsibility to dispose it.

The caller will have to deal with it.

If you were returning an object whose life-cycle is managed by your class, as it is often the case with properties, then you'd have to implement the interface.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a method instead of a property.
Quoting from Microsofts Framework Design Guidelines

> [...] DO use a property, rather than a method, if the value of the property 
>   is stored in the process memory and the property would just provide
>   access to the value.  For example, a member that retrieves the name of
>   a Customer from a  field stored in the object should be a property
>
> DO use a method, rather than a property, in the following situations: 
>   The operation is orders of magnitude slower than a field access 
>   would be. If you are even considering providing an asynchro-  nous
>   version of an operation to avoid blocking the thread, it is  very
>   likely that the operation is too expensive to be a property. In 
>   particular, operations that access the network or the file system 
>   (other than once for initialization) should likely be methods, not 
>   properties.  […]

Answer (score 1):

Not Really, The purpose of using Interfaces generally is to make sure we don't miss something, It's always a best practice to implement well-defined Interfaces as they may save you from a lot of trouble in the long run.

Technically the interface **IDisposable** just has a dispose method in it and you can always write your own **Dispose** method with your own logic.

and Yes! If you don't even use that Dispose method to waive off the unnecessary objects from your memory, it will always be handled by the C# Garbage Collector at the end of the day but I won't be very happy with **100+ mbs** of unmanaged resources sitting in my memory.

Anyways the answer is not really but Use it often as It keeps everything streamlined.

Comment: 1. IDisposable is a established way of signaling use of unmanaged resources. This is not true of your own interfaces. Depending on your tools chain undisposed objects are going to be highlighted as warnings or errors. I cannot recommend the usage of an self made interface.2. The main problem with unmanaged resources is not memory but the unmanaged resource itself. The C# gargabe collector will misjudge unmanaged resource and delay collection of them to keep performance up. This will lead to resource starvation followed by instability and crashes. Do not rely on non deterministic behaviour.